# Magento site css not load after editing web/unsecure/base_url in core_config_data in mysql database

Tags: mysql, css, magento, magento-1.8

Before changing in my database,  my `web/secure/base_url` had as value `www.foo.com/foo/` and my website loaded successfully. After change to `www.foo.com` css files are not loaded, I move back to my old value but result It's still the same, no css files are loaded.
How can I fix it?

Comment: have you cleared magento cache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your site was located in foo.com/foo/ and you changed it to foo.com then there are two possible reasons;

One, your site with corresponding styles is located in a sub directory /foo/ and therefore altering the entry to foo.com won't load any styles unless your style sheets erc have been moved to the root level.

Secondly, you must have the trailing slash "/", so any entry in either the http or http fields in the core_config_data table should either be;

www.foo.com/

Or

www.foo.com/foo/

Hope that helps in some way.

Oh, and always clear the cache.  Magento relies heavily on cache and I've been caught ou several times with this.
Also goes without saying, but back up before making any changes :)

Good luck

Comment: Thank you for your reply, after clearing the cache, everything is back in order.

Comment: 80% of the problems with baseurl changes are fixed by clearing the cache afterwards. 20% are not having file/folder permissions correct so that Magento writes its cache in the system `/tmp` which leads to the mysterious non-clearable cache (even by manual delete) and the old baseurl settings seemingly remaining more or less permanent.